# AWS naked domain redirect when using CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I'm in the process of setting up a static website which is hosted on S3, uses a SSL/TLS certificate provided by Certificate Manager and is fronted by CloudFront.

I've been trying to find an authoritative resource which will help me understand how to configure the various services so that: http://example.com, http://www.example.com, https://example.com will all be redirected to https://www.example.com.

So far, I've only come up with half-answers which cover doing this without CloudFront/TLS or which attempt to do the reverse mapping -- www.example.com to example.com. (I'm waiting for my most recent attempt at reverse engineering this to propagate but I'm not terribly confident it's going to work.)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS S3 Redirect for Route53 not working for HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63178730/aws-s3-redirect-for-route53-not-working-for-https)

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP to HTTPS redirect is built into CloudFront (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-viewers-to-cloudfront.html) while redirecting the root domain to www could be more complex.

A simple and effective approach would be to map the root domain to a separate S3 bucket (as the buckets must match the domain name), and setup the redirect within the bucket itself (see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/redirect-website-requests.html) or with an HTML redirect in index.html.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='http://www.example.com'" />
```

Home it helps!

Comment: Thanks for this. I believe the solution I'm looking for will require some additional granularity (e.g. Certificate Manager settings, CloudFront Alternate Domain Names, Cloud Front Origins, etc.). I've hit upon a workable solution for myself and will answer my own question shortly -- unless you want to flesh yours out.