# AWS S3 Redirect for Route53 not working for HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

I am attempting to use AWS S3 Static Website Redirect to allow redirects from an Apex domain (example.com) to the [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) domain.

I used the following guide https://medium.com/faun/redirect-naked-domain-to-www-with-https-on-aws-route-53-e620e4ce989d

In Route53, I have created an A record for the apex domain `example.com`

```
example.com    A    Simple   s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com.
```

The `www.example.domain` points to a cloudfront distribution which distributes my website.
The cloudfront domain will redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS

```
www.example.com   A    Simple    *************.cloudfront.net.
```

In S3, I have created a bucket for `example.com` and set it up to redirect all requests
[[image: example.com s3 bucket redirect rules]
The bucket is public and empty

The resulting behavior works for HTTP but times out for HTTPS

```
http://example.com -> https://www.example.com
https://example.com -> ETIMEDOUT
http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com
https://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com
```

How can I fix this setup so that
`https://example.com -> https://www.example.com`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is S3 static website hosting doesn't support HTTPS. [[ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)]

So you need to add a CloudFront in front of `example.com` s3 bucket and configure proper DNS records pointing to it

Comment: That fixed it for me. Now dealing with an ACM SSL issue where the browser is not regarding the certificate as authentic, will look into that separately. Thanks.

Answer (score 60):

### Problem Description

So, ideally you want all the followings to work:

```
1) https://example.com     → https://www.example.com   (naked to www)
2) http://www.example.com  → https://www.example.com   (http to https)
3) http://example.com      → https://www.example.com   (naked http to www https)
4) https://www.example.com →  actually show the content as the canonical URL!
```

Note that the requirement #3 above can be broken down into **two steps**, which would be a combination of #1 and then #2.

```
3B) http://example.com → http://www.example.com → https://www.example.com
```

All these `→`s are a HTTP 301 Permanent Redirect.

### Requirements

So, you need 3 pieces here:

1. A **URL Redirect** (`example.com → www.example.com`)
2. *[HTTPS Support]* An **SSL certificate** to cover naked subdomain as well as www (it can be two in one, free in Certification Manager)
3. *[HTTPS Support]* A **Protocol Redirect** (`http:// → https://`)

### Solution

This solution requires many pieces in AWS that should be all free! (or no additional cost)

#### Step 1) Create a URL Redirect in S3

Create a S3 Static Hosting Website and have it redirect to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).
[image]

**Notes:**

1. Make sure it's publicly accessible.
2. Test that the URL works and landing on it actually does the redirect. (or test in terminal via `curl -v`)
3. Always test the full URL that **contains the region** (i.e. `.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`)

#### Step 2) Create an SSL Certificate for naked domain in Certificate Manager

Go to https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/acm/home?region=us-west-2#/ (change your region to your preferred one) and request a public certificate.  Make sure you put both `example.com` and `www.example.com` there.  Verify it in Route 53.

#### Step 3) Create a Protocol Redirect in CloudFront

Go to CloudFront and create a distribution with **Viewer Protocol Policy** of "Http => HTTPS redirect" and having its origin be the full URL of the S3 bucket above.

[image]

**Notes:**

1. Do NOT point it to S3 directly.  Let is point to the full URL of S3 bucket's static website.
2. Caching Policy can be No Cache.
3. Alternate Domain Names should be your example.com and SSL certification of Step 2 should be fed into it.
4. Verify in the "Origins" tab that you are pointing to the S3 full URL path.

#### Step 4) Have a DNS record in Route53

Finally, go to your route53 DNS record and have it point the naked domain as `A` record to the CloudFront distribution of step 3, which should be like `d21k2s1234123.cloudfront.net`!

[image]

Tada!

Comment: Insanity to achieve what is such a common use case, but yep still the only way!

Comment: Thank you for a write-up, I hoped it would work with my legacy non-Route53 registrar/NS (webmasters.com) in the 4th step but the A record there has to be an IP address, it just ignores a dns name in A.

Comment: @kuz8, I'd say try other types, like `CNAME` or `ANAME`.

Comment: they're too old to support it, I was forced to move NS to cloudflare. 
Another way I found was to use free / paid service called redirect.pizza - they even do R3 https cert for free. Or to move NS to Route53.

Comment: What a freaking puzzle.. But this answer was a life savior for me, thanks a lot man.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped me a lot. I have only one thing to optimize. Do not use the http to https redirect in the CloudFront distribution. Allow both http and https and instead select https in the S3 redirect. This will lead to fewer 301 redirect hops and you still always end up at the encrypted www endpoint.

Comment: Also for the 301 redirect in S3, the bucket does not need to be publicly accessible.

Comment: Big thanks for the detailed explanation here. Absolutely bonkers that it takes all of this just to add a redirect!

Comment: I got hung up big time by selecting the bucket directly in Cloudfront versus pasting in the Bucket website endpoint (the one that has "website" in the URL). Ugh. Finally figured it out with the help of https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/route-53-redirect-to-another-domain/

Comment: Didn't work for me when I redirect the other way around (`www` redirects to `non-www`)

Comment: The link evolross provided now redirects to [How can I redirect one domain to another in Route 53?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/route-53-redirect-to-another-domain) at [AWS re:Post](https://repost.aws/). And this post includes links to two other posts of particular interest--[How do I redirect an apex domain to its subdomain or any other domain using S3 and Route 53?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53) and [How do I use CloudFront to serve HTTPS requests for my Amazon S3 bucket?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3).

Comment: Important: the bucket has to have `https` as protocol

Comment: This tripped me up for a couple of hours so I am leaving this here for everyone: In the Cloudfront Origin setting, for Protocol choose "HTTP only" -- It's sort of counter-intuitive but that's what you need.

Comment: as far as I can see here, the bucket is actually playing no role here. i was able to achieve the desired effect despite bypassing the bucket—simply creating a certificate (i.e., for both `domain.tld` and `www.domain.tld`), creating a CloudFront, with origin `www.domain.tld` (directly, not the bucket!!!) and Alternate Domain Name `domain.tld`, and finally aliasing my apex to the CloudFront distribution. no bucket at all.