# How to redirect naked urls to www over https in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have set up redirects from these below URLs:

```
http://tweepsbook.com
http://www.tweepsbook.com
```

to

```
https://www.tweepsbook.com
```

But I am facing issues with redirecting `https://tweepsbook.com` to `https://www.tweepsbook.com`
I have an SSL certificate for both domains.

Currently, S3 allows redirects via `HTTP` only. I want redirects for `HTTPS` as well

I am currently using AWS S3 bucket, Elastic Beanstalk, ACM, Route 53.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS S3 Redirect for Route53 not working for HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63178730/aws-s3-redirect-for-route53-not-working-for-https)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an Application Load Balancer with your Elastic Beanstalk application, you can use a combination of these two features to [redirect the root domain to www](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-to-another-domain-with-alb/), and [redirect HTTP to HTTPS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/).

Comment: As I said, I am redirecting root to www over http, but I am facing problems redirecting it over https. Also, I am able to redirect http to https.

Comment: @AnshAgarwal yes I saw that, but I'm trying to show you a better way to do all that without needing the S3 buckets at all, which will also solve the issues are are currently running into.

Comment: Understood. Let me try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To provide https access to S3 objects in a bucket which is in website mode, through have to use **CloudFront**:

- [How do I use CloudFront to serve HTTPS requests for my Amazon S3 bucket?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am not able to find the alias when I went to change it for the root domain in route 53.
Note: I don't know if this is relevant or not, but I have an SSL certificate for South (Mumbai) and Virginia as well. I needed an SSL for Virginia coz cloud distribution ask for Virginia and nothing else.