# Why does CloudFront pointing to S3 static website works, but not when it's a "Redirect request" bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**Background**: I'm trying to configure a static website hosting on S3 for `adomain.com`. Specifically, I want to redirect `http://adomain.com`, `http://www.adomain.com` and `https://www.adomain.com` all to `https://adomain.com`. For that, I've been following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67222388/2076973).

Very shortly, it says to create a Bucket with the name `adomain.com` to host the website. And then, another bucket, with name `www.adomain.com`, and set *"Hosting type: Redirect request"* pointing to the `adomain.com` bucket. Everything works fine until this.

However, I got stuck on step #3. I created the CloudFront distribution with the origin set to the URL of the `www.adomain.com` bucket (ie. full bucket URL `www.adomain.com.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com`). Let's call this `CloudFront Dist WWW`.

[I also created a second CloudFront distribution, with origin set to the URL of the `adomain.com` bucket, let's call it `CloudFront Dist non-WWW`].

**But when try to access that `CloudFront Dist WWW`'s `Distribution domain name` (eg. `https://lotsofchars123.cloudfront.net`), it doesn't load.**

On the other hand, when I try the `CloudFront Dist non-WWW`'s `Distribution domain name`, it does load. **Why is that?**

I must also point out that both S3's URLs work perfectly (ie. both `adomain.com.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com` and `www.adomain.com.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com` load)

Also, when I set the Route 53 hosted zone `www.adomain.com` to route traffic to `CloudFront Dist WWW`'s `Distribution domain name`, it does load (except for `http`, ie. `http://www.adomain.com` works, but `https://www.adomain.com` doesn't)

**edit**:

[Cloudfront Distribution Config](https://pastebin.com/Qu6z7bv7)

Comment: It would be helpful to see the configurations with your domain/IDs redacted. Can you use AWS-CLI to provide the distribution configurations?

`aws cloudfront list-distributions`
`aws cloudfront get-distribution-config --id XXXXXXXXX`

Comment: @ChrisMiller Hi Thanks for taking the time! I updated the answer with the data you requested

Comment: When you say "it doesn't load" are you getting a 403 error on https://lotsofchars123.cloudfront.net or does it just hang indefinitely?

Comment: @ChrisMiller the `lotsofchars123.cloudfront.net` gets stuck on loading... on the computer, the `http://www` version works (ie. the route pointing to `lotsofchars123.cloudfront.net`), but on my iphone it gives `ERROR 403`. Same thing on curl. (for `http://www`, curl gives `ERROR 403`). Finally, `https://www` never works (_"this site cannot provide a secure connection"_). I have no idea what is wrong, because the origin for `lotsofchars123.cloudfront.net` works normally.

Comment: I built this out in my account and am able to replicate similar issues. I will try to respond in the next 24-ish hours.

Comment: @ChrisMiller wow, thanks for taking the time! Really appreciate someone more knowledged looking into this, because I have literally no idea